# How to query linked documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'd like to know if there's a way to directly search within a linked collection.

I'm using Express with mongoosejs

I have the following situation.

I have 3 collections, **deal**, **product** and **store** and I have associated **product** and **store** with the **deal collection**.

```
const DealSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  product: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'product'
  },
  shop: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'shop'
  },
  ...
});
```

In my collection product, I have a field called upc.

I have a controller that handles deals creation, however before I create a deal, I want to check whether or not there's already a deal with the same UPC in this store if so I'll only update the confirmedBy field.

This is my controller

```
async create(req, res) {
  const dealProps = req.body;
  const product = await Products.findOne({ upc: dealProps.upc });
  let deal;
  if (product) {
    deal = await Deals.findOne({ product: product._id });
    if (deal.shop.toString() === dealProps.shop.toString()) {
      const updatedDeal = await Deals.findOneAndUpdate({ product: product._id }, {
        $push: {confirmedBy: dealProps.user }
      });
      res.send(updatedDeal);
    }
  } else {
    deal = await (new Deals(dealProps)).save();
    res.send(deal);
  }
}
```

I've tried to search directly within the product collection like this:

```
const product = await Deals.findOne({'product.upc': dealProps.upc });
```

However it returns null.

Is there a way to search directly within a linked collection? Do I need to create an index for the upc field in the product collection?

If not, should I rethink my deals collection to add the upc and storeId to simplify the lookup?

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.